# how to insert only new row from excel sheet to database

Tags: c#

i am working on importing data from excel sheet to database.i am able to successfully import the data from excel to database.i want to know how can i add only new row from excel sheet to database without adding previous data.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < exceltable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i > 1)
                {
                    DataRow row = exceltable.Rows[i];
                    object ID = row[0].ToString();


                    if (ID != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ID.ToString().Trim()))
                    {
                        Int16 CustID = Convert.ToInt16(ID);
                        string CustName = row[1].ToString();
                        string CardScheme = row[2].ToString();
                        string Outlet = row[3].ToString();
                        string TerminalNum = row[4].ToString();
                        Int32 Terminal = Convert.ToInt32(TerminalNum);

                        string Date1 = row[5].ToString();
                        DateTime Date = Convert.ToDateTime(Date1);

                        string Time = row[6].ToString();
                        DateTime DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(Time);

                        string Amount1 = row[7].ToString();
                        double Amount = Convert.ToDouble(Amount1);

                        string columnNames = "CustID,CustName,CardScheme,Outlet,TerminalNum,TranDate,TranDateTime,Amount";
                        string query1 = String.Format("insert into customer({0})values ('{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}')", columnNames, CustID, CustName, CardScheme, Outlet, Terminal, Date, DateTime, Amount);
                        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query1, connection);
                        com.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    }
                    **// else if (i==exceltable.Rows[exceltable.Rows.Count-1]-1)
                    //{
                    //   DataRow Newrow = exceltable.NewRow();
                    //   Newrow["CustID"] = row[0].ToString();
                    //   Newrow["CustName"] = row[1].ToString();
                    //   Newrow["CardScheme"] = row[2].ToString();
                    //   Newrow["Outlet"] = row[3].ToString();
                    //   Newrow["TerminalNum"] = row[4].ToString();
                    //   Newrow["TranDate"] = row[5].ToString();
                    //   Newrow["TranDateTime"] = row[6].ToString();
                    //   Newrow["Amount"] = row[7].ToString();
                    //   exceltable.Rows.Add(Newrow);
                    //   exceltable.AcceptChanges();

                    //}**

                }

            }


                DataRow lastrow=exceltable.Rows[exceltable.Rows.Count-1];
                if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastrow.ToString().Trim()))
                {
                  string Count = lastrow[4].ToString();
                  Int16 TotalRows = Convert.ToInt16(Count);
                  string Sum = lastrow[7].ToString();
                  double TotalAmount = Convert.ToDouble(Sum);

                  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tblExcel(TotalRows,TotalAmount) values('"+TotalRows+"','"+TotalAmount+"')",connection);
                  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }                

                return true;
        }
```

Now i want some guidance..above code insert the data from excel sheet to database..now i want to know do i need to add the code for inserting new row within this code or do i need to add somewhere else and also i have tried using NewRow() method of datatable which i have marked in comments as i had doubt about it..am i going in right direction..Do guide me.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to check the data against what you have in your database. 
There should be a Key which makes that row unique.

```
var row = RowFromExcel(); //Row from Excel
var uniqueKey = row.Key;

if (!FindRowInDbWithKeyExists(uniqueKey))
{
    //If not found in Db then insert new row.
}
```

Comment: Can u explain me what do you mean by RowFromExcel() and row.Key..Is key a property..

Comment: @Nazima, RowFromExcel() is a method that will return a class or just a list of values, which is basically each excel cell in the excel row. The row.Key is which ever cell make that row unique. So lets say you were returing a List String, and the cell that made that row unique was the second cell, you would do something like this. var uniqueKey = rows[1]; <= gets the second value. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify the database you are using, you can choose to ignore duplicating records while inserting, your table must have a primary key.

For oracle(11g) you can use `ignore_row_on_dupkey_index` hint with the insert statement.

For SQL Server you need to create the index with `IGNORE_DUP_KEY`

For MySQL you can use `IGNORE` hint with you insert statement.

You will have to process the entire excel sheet every time, but only NEW rows will be inserted  into the table.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is not direct solution. You have to come up with some tricks on this. 
What i might do this, know how many records i have inserted into DB so far (assuming the new records are inserted at the end) and then any records further from that number will be added to DB.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you upload your datatable to a Temp table. Just run a delete statement to remove the rows that are already in you main database table.  You can then just insert the remaining new rows.